# Show information on visualforce page only for certain profiles

Tags: visualforce, profile, customer-portal

I've added a profile recently and I want to display an extra button for that profile on the visualforce page. I've tried a couple of things but it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I've tried:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="loggedAtkins" layout="block" 
      rendered="{!AND(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Atkins'), $Site.LoginEnabled)}" >    
 </apex:outputPanel>
```

I've sucessfully did it for Guest and not guest user accounts using this method

```
<apex:outputPanel id="notlogged" layout="block" 
          rendered="{!AND(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'), $Site.LoginEnabled)}" >

<apex:outputPanel id="logged" layout="block" 
                   rendered="{!NOT(ISPICKVAL($User.UserType,'Guest'))}" >
```

Does anyone know how to show certain information only for specific users.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it works when you use the global profile variable:

```
rendered="{!$Profile.Name == 'Your Profile Name'}"
```